# Can I monitor my network traffic in such a way that may help diagnose why I consistently lose connection in an online multiplayer video game?

Tags: networking, vpn, gaming

I recently purchased a game with online multiplayer. Whenever I attempt to play any of the PVP modes, I am dropped, without fail, at the 5 to 6 minute mark of any PVP event.

**I am trying to determine if there is any way, or even a point in me trying, to identify where the problem lies.**

I have discovered that by using a VPN service, I am able to play without the slightest problem. But this isn't an ideal solution. My, entirely unqualified opinion is that my ISP is "interfering" with the game connection, possibly as a security measure considering that it is so consistent at 5 to 6 minutes.

Also, I have a friend in within 10 miles of me with a different ISP that has no problems. Unfortunately, changing to his ISP isn't an option at the moment, nor a guarantee.

I have been in contact with the game's support staff for a week, following all of their instructions, and have reached the point where I'm getting the brush-off. I want to see if there's anything more I can do to identify where the issue lies.

Are there any guides or tools that would be able to monitor the network traffic for the game and help determine why this consistently happens? Or is this a waste of time?

Comment: Have you tried contacting your ISP with the information you have deduced?  Probably won't help as they probably will deny it.. but it might help and you have nothing to lose.

Comment: That was my next step and I was just sitting down to do that when I saw your reply. I agree, they'll likely deny any problem, but we'll see what happens. Thanks!